# BottomNavigationView rendering issue with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, android-framelayout, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented single activity multiple fragments application design.I have Constraint Layout as the root of the activity and a Frame Layout is hosting all the fragments in my application.I also have a Bottom Navigation View (from com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView).
I want to have a Bottom Navigation View with all of my fragment's User Interface.

**Problem** : I am having problem rendering the Bottom Navigation View.***It does not sticks to the bottom of the parent,It just floats in a layout.***
The constraints that I have applied on the Bottom Navigation View does not seems to working properly or may be I am not using them correctly.

**Observations** : I have tried some configurations to understand the problem.I applied background color to the constraint layout (Black),App's accent color to the frame layout and observed that the constraint's for the Bottom Navigation View have not applied correctly.
When I launched the app the Bottom Navigation View floats and then follows the constraints and is working properly but when I paused the activity and then after resume the activity the Bottom Navigation View fails to follow the constraints.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".module.MainView">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorNavIcon"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorNavText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/wkd_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout on start of the activity :

[image]

Layout on resume of the activity :

[image]

The black area below the Bottom Navigation View is the Constraint Layout.
I want the Bottom Navigation View to follow the constraints every time I open the particular fragment.

Answer (score 2):

> Your constraint is proper still as you are giving all constraint to framelayout try width and height with 0dp like below.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_got_it"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_profile" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: according to my observations, When the fragment was resumed somehow it was not able to find the height for root layout causing the bottom navigation view to jump of its constraint.I observed something in my manifest file when I was inspecting the issue and I found out that my activity has the attributes like **`noHistory=true`** and I think that is the one which is causing that problem.When I removed the attribute everything started working perfectly like a magic.